# preg_match to find links to images and url

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to use preg_match to find urls mentioned inside  and  tags so that I can replace them with the updated domain name. Right now I am just trying to get the search script for this figured out in href tags so that I can print the urls found. Here is what I have:

```
$matches = array();
$search="domain.com";
preg_match('|(<a\s*[^>]*href=[\'"]?)|',$prod['value'],$matches);
echo '<p>'.$matches[1].'</p>';
```

`$prod['value']` refers to the content that I am trying to sift through

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

## Your Code

```
$matches = array();
$search="domain.com";
preg_match('|(<a\s*[^>]*href=[\'"]?)|',$prod['value'],$matches);
echo '<p>'.$matches[1].'</p>';
```

Firstly, `$matches` doesn't need to be defined before the `preg_match` call. You just have to provide a variable name and `PHP` won't so much as throw a **notice**.

Secondly, `$search` doesn't seem to be relevant to the question?..

Third... Bearing in mind that you haven't shown example input I'm going to *make an assumption* that you actually want `preg_match_all` so that you can get a list of all `URLs` from the input.

Fourth, following on from three, that means you need `var_dump` or `print_r` instead of `echo` as the content of `$matches[X]` will be an `array`.

### Regex

Okay, so now for what your regex pattern actually does...

```
(<a\s*[^>]*href=['"]?)
```

- `(` - starts a capture group
- `<a\s*` - matches `<a` followed by *0 or more* white space characters
- `[^>]*` - matches *0 or more* characters that are not `>`
- `href=` - matches `href=`
- `['"]?` - optionally matches either `'` or `"`
- `)` - ends capture group

This all means that run against the **example input** your regex will match `<a href="` from the first link example (google) and `<a class="fancyStyle" href="` from the second link example (youtube).

```
/**
Output from:

preg_match_all('|(<a\s*[^>]*href=[\'"]?)|', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

*/
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "<a href=""
    [1]=>
    string(28) "<a class="fancyStyle" href=""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "<a href=""
    [1]=>
    string(28) "<a class="fancyStyle" href=""
  }
}
```

## Working Code

There are a few problems with your code, but, the one that is stopping you from getting the expected `URL` is that you simply stop capturing **before** you get to it.

The following regex will match `URL`s that are within the `href` attribute of `a` tags.

```
#<a\s.*?(?:href=['"](.*?)['"]).*?>#is
```

### Explanation

- `<a` - matches the opening of an `a` tag
- `\s.*?` - matches a white space character followed by **any** character *0 or more* times
- `(?:` - creates a non-capturing group
- `href=` - matches `href=`
- `['"]` - matches either `'` or `"`
- `(.*?)` - creates a capture group and matches *0 or more* characters before...
- `['"]` - matches `'` or `"`
- `)` - ends the non-capturing group
- `.*?>` - matches any character *0 or more* times followed by `>`
- `i` - makes the regex case insensitive
- `s` - makes `.` match all characters (including new lines)

### Working Example

```
preg_match_all('#<a\s.*?(?:href=[\'"](.*?)[\'"]).*?>#is', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

/**
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(34) "<a href="http://www.google.co.uk">"
    [1]=>
    string(65) "<a class="fancyStyle" href="http://www.youtube.com" id="link136">"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(23) "http://www.google.co.uk"
    [1]=>
    string(22) "http://www.youtube.com"
  }
}

*/
```

## Example Input

All code uses the following as input into the `preg_match` function...

```
$string = <<<EOC
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title of page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Main Page title</h1>
        <p>
            The following is a <a href="http://www.google.co.uk">link to google</a>.
            This is <a class="fancyStyle" href="http://www.youtube.com" id="link136">another link</a>
        </p>
    </body>
    </html>
EOC;
```

Comment: Wow thank you Steven. Your explanation was very thorough. I will try this and let you know. I would like to know if you can point me a to a resource where you learned about regex expressions. I would like to read up on it so I can understand it a bit better.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ - That's a good reference click on "Tutorials" at the top and you'll find explanations for everything from the basics such as character classes `[]` to the more advanced stuff like `lokarounds` etc